# Ajax Request is not working To Controller

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

My Script is this when I click button nothing to happen or not to redirect?

```
<script>
    $("#New").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Refrences/Create',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "html",
            sucess: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#myPartialContainer').html(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error");
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

My Controller is this but at break point its working correctly?

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CandidateID = new SelectList(db.InterviewCanidates, "CandidateID", "Name");
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return View ("Error");
    } 
}
```

My Button is Simply when i click Button no request is send to controller?

```
<div id="New" class="btn btn-success">Create New</div>
```

mean nothing. No javascript errors, no errors on the MySQL query, not even POST data in the console.log. Just a taunting batch o' silence. Even if I comment out all the code page and just echo the data I sent over to it, nothing. Here's the  page (the class exists, the functions work, I'm using them on a dozen or so other pages)

Comment: your are not sending data to controller in ajax call

Comment: Is `sucess` a typo? (its `success`)

Comment: So it was a typo in your code after all. You should delete the question. Its of no use to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it will work

```
$.get('/Refrences/Create',function(data){ 
 alert(data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
        $("#New").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //alert("Call");
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Refrences")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "text",
                sucess: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#myPartialContainer').html(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Change only  *Url:'@Url.Action("Create", "Refrences")',*  and  dataType:"text",